# Publish data from PCI-6229

Tags: ros, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I want to read encoder data from a NI PCI-6229 and publish it to a topic (for gmapping).
Are there any tutorials about this or can someone help me with this?
I can't seem to get started.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232340/publish-data-from-pci-6229/) by [Bert](https://answers.ros.org/users/26233/bert/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2016-04-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am dealing with NI PCI-6224. It works when using the Comedi driver on Qt for Linux. [Comedi reference here](http://stm.lbl.gov/comedi/doc/index.html) So I suppose writing a node with Comedi may help. Yet I haven't tried and worked everything out.

---

Originally posted by [mizu_lily](https://answers.ros.org/users/26610/mizu_lily/) with karma: 16 on 2016-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0